# Winforms disabling keyboard input on textbox but keeping textbox enabled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The scenario is like that;

I need to disable textbox to take input from user ***by keyboard***. But textbox should take inputs using kind of devices like **barcode reader.** I thought to hold a timer and take the timespan between two key strokes (not clear yet). But maybe there is a property or smarter algorithm for that ?

p.s. it is a windows forms application.

Comment: WinForms or WebForms or something else? Your question is tagged only with C# and you are talking about some textbox, but there are textboxes everywhere.

Comment: Is there some sort of API for the barcode reader or does it just send input to the keyboard buffer?

Comment: I dont want to consider there is an API. The Barcode Reader can be any Barcode reader. So I need to find a generic solution that will work for all of them.

Comment: Most likely your bar code reader functions just like a keyboard. So Winforms won't be able to distinguish between your barcode reader or any other keyboard for its text input. For this you would go low level (below C#) to detect where the text input originated. And maybe you might be clocking the beginning and ending of text input? But I guess the code will be somewhat clumsy that way.

Comment: @mahditahsildari 'the barcode reader thing' is probably the same as any keyboard input. It is no object with 'ScannedText' properties or any kind. Its just an text input device.

Comment: Yes, @mahdi. I dont think there is something like scannedText.

Comment: I didn't know what barcode reader is. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you'll need to support any barcode reader, which usually emulate a keyboard, therefore there probably isn't an easy way to programmatically distinguish between input from a keyboard and a barcode reader.

Your idea about using timing is a good one, although I'd do something slightly differently. I'd add a `Timer` to the `Form` and start it when the first character is entered into the `TextBox`. The timer should be set to a very short time span and should have auto-restart disabled. When the timer goes off, check if the `TextBox` has a valid barcode, and if does, process it. Either way, clear the text box afterwards.

It would then appear to anyone attempting to use the keyboard that their typed text simply disappears, while a barcode scanner (which 'types' very fast) would still work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to track 'keyboard press' event?
I don't think what automatically pasting something will trigger 'keyboard press' event.